# How to get the latest value per time interval in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT RIGHT(timestamp,LEN(timestamp) -12) as DailyTime, left(roundtrip, LEN(roundtrip) -2) as HalfHourDuration, site_code
FROM tblServer_Status
WHERE timestamp >= dateadd(day, datediff(day,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),'19000101') AND timestamp < dateadd(day, datediff(day,'19000101',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)+1,'19000101') AND server = 'ServerName' AND site_code = 'A' 
GROUP BY timestamp, roundtrip, site_code HAVING(((COUNT(site_code))>0))
ORDER BY timestamp
```

I have this code that gives me this kind of output

```
| DailyTime | HalfHourDuration | Site_Code|
   12:00AM          122              A
   12:00AM          143              A
   12:00AM          242              A
   12:30AM          112              A
   12:30AM          222              A
   12:30AM          462              A
   01:00AM          322              A
   01:00AM          642              A
   01:00AM          322              A
   01:30AM          146              A
   01:30AM          167              A
   01:30AM          116              A
   02:00AM          163              A
   02:00AM          145              A
   02:00AM          121              A
   02:30AM          149              A
   02:30AM          135              A
   02:30AM          111              A
   ...................................
```

But I need to get the Latest duration per time.
Like this one

```
| DailyTime | HalfHourDuration | Site_Code|
   12:00AM          242              A
   12:30AM          462              A
   01:00AM          322              A
   01:30AM          116              A
   02:00AM          121              A
   02:30AM          111              A
```

Something like that.
can anyone help me configure my codes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `row_number()`:

```
with t as (
      <your query here without order by>
     )
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by DailyTime
                                order by HalfHourDuration desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Dude. Thanks. But the order of the time is by number. Can u help me Sort it by AM - PM.

Comment: I need the sorting of time from 12:00AM to 11:30 PM. Thanks for the answer by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Add Max function to your column HalfHourDuration.
This will list out the maximum value of the roundtrip alone grouping by timestamp